# Netmiko - Enter configuration terminal mode

Tags: python, netmiko

I am trying to use Netmiko and work in 'configuration terminal' mode.
**Why there only 'enable' mode function and not 'configuration terminal' mode.?** (i.e : net_connect.enable())

**My program should do these steps:**

1. login
2. change to enable mode
3. change to configure terminal
4. insert restricted license ( in configuration terminal mode )
5. run '_shell' to change from CLI to regular Linux bash.

****Editing****
I tried the following command to enter config_mode and got 'ValueError'.

```
net_connect.find_prompt()
net_connect.enable()
net_connect.find_prompt()
net_connect.config_mode()
net_connect.find_prompt()
```

**Logs:**

```py
>>> from netmiko import ConnectHandler
>>> net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', host='r-hpc-sw19', username='admin', password='admin') 
>>> net_connect.find_prompt()                                                                                    
'r-hpc-sw19 [standalone: master] >'                                                                              
>>> net_connect.enable()                                                                                         
'enable\r\r\n\rr-hpc-sw19 [standalone: master] # '                                                               
>>> net_connect.find_prompt()                                                                                    
'r-hpc-sw19 [standalone: master] #'                                                                              
>>> net_connect.config_mode()                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                               
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                            
  File "/labhome/arielwe/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/cisco_base_connection.py", line 48, in config_mode
    return super().config_mode(                                                                                       
  File "/labhome/arielwe/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1766, in config_mode    
    raise ValueError("Failed to enter configuration mode.")                                                           
ValueError: Failed to enter configuration mode.
```

Second Try:

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', host='r-hpc-sw19', username='admin', password='admin')
net_connect.find_prompt()
net_connect.enable()
net_connect.find_prompt()
cfg = net_connect.send_config_set(["show version | json-print"])
net_connect.find_prompt()

>>> from netmiko import ConnectHandler
>>> net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', host='r-hpc-sw19', username='admin', password='admin')
>>> net_connect.find_prompt()
'r-hpc-sw19 [standalone: master] >'
>>> net_connect.enable()
'enable\r\r\n\rr-hpc-sw19 [standalone: master] # '
>>> net_connect.find_prompt()
'r-hpc-sw19 [standalone: master] #'
>>> cfg = net_connect.send_config_set(["show version | json-print"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/labhome/arielwe/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1876, in send_config_set
    output += self.config_mode(*cfg_mode_args)
  File "/labhome/arielwe/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/cisco_base_connection.py", line 48, in config_mode
    return super().config_mode(
  File "/labhome/arielwe/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1766, in config_mode
    raise ValueError("Failed to enter configuration mode.")
ValueError: Failed to enter configuration mode.
>>> net_connect.find_prompt()
```

Thanks,
Ariel.

Comment: You should include your try with your question so others can help. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there only 'enable' mode function and not 'configuration terminal' mode.?

There is a `configure terminal` mode in `netmiko`, using [`conn.config_mode()`](https://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/docs/netmiko/index.html#netmiko.BaseConnection.config_mode)  sends `configure terminal` to the remote device.

However, you can use [`send_config_set()`](https://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/docs/netmiko/index.html#netmiko.BaseConnection.send_config_set) which enters configuration mode by default and exits it after the last command was sent. An example of using `send_config_set()`

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",
    "secret": "cisco",
    "fast_cli": False,
}

with ConnectHandler(**device) as conn:
    if not conn.check_enable_mode():
        conn.enable()
    cfg = conn.send_config_set(["interface Loopback 212", "shutdown"])

print(cfg)
```

```
RTR1(config)#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
RTR1(config)#interface Loopback 212
RTR1(config-if)#shutdown
RTR1(config-if)#end
RTR1#
```

**EDIT**

Since neither `send_config_set()` nor `config_mode()` work, you can use `send_command_timing()` and write the command yourself instead of using the methods in netmiko.

`send_command_timing()` is **delay-based** and not **pattern-based** like `send_command()`. the timing method waits for sometime and sends the command after, it searches for no patterns. You can also read the first part of this [documentation link](http://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/COMMON_ISSUES.html) to know more about `send_command_timing()`

```py
net_conn.send_command_timing("enable")
net_conn.send_command_timing("configure terminal")
```

Comment: You can see that i'm getting an exception after this line 'config_mode() '. the python code and exception is attached above. Anything else is missing?

Comment: @ArielWeiser Have you tried using the `send_config_set()` method? I just want to make sure that netmiko detects the prompt correctly. Otherwise, the answer will be edited

Comment: I edited my question, you can see that send_config_set() doesn't work as well. please note that even if it worked, i'm trying to enter configuration terminal mode and run commands ( instead of exiting from the configuration terminal after each command )

Comment: @ArielWeiser This means netmiko is unable to detect the config mode pattern correctly. You can use `send_command_timing()` same as `send_command()` but delay-based not pattern-based. I’ll update my answer as well.

Comment: Great it works!
I just need to parse my ASCI output. should I use 're.complie' or netmiko has elegant solution for it?

Comment: @ArielWeiser You can simply use `ascii()`  to get the ASCII output, or `your_str_var.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: I think I found out why you are getting the error. The `device_type` is `cisco_ios` and your device is most probably not a Cisco device. Kirk, netmiko author, defined the device types and some predefined screen scraping patterns to detect the prompt of each vendor properly. Try to select the correct device type.

Answer (score 0):

You must determine the privilege level for the user or use a secret password to enter the config mode from ssh.

Without that,

```
Conn.enable() & conn.send_config_set()
```

will not work